# How to get corresponding cells in a column for all cells in a different column that match some criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Spreadsheet that goes something like this:

```
3/10    A    50
6/10    P    600
7/10    Q    75
10/9    A    750
...
```

I want all elements of Column 1 and Column 3 where Column 2 matches some criteria (`==A`). Say, something like:

```
3/10    50
10/9    750
...
```

Any tips?

Comment: Look into `Query`

Comment: @ScottCraner Wow, this is basically like SQL! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Column 1 is `A`, please try:

```
=query(A:C,"select A,C where B='A'")
```

Comment: Yes, I had used some variant of ``query`` and it works great. Thanks! :)